# Check C++ shared dependencies at runtime (ldd on self)

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, dlopen, ldd

Is there a way to check or access the names of the libraries a C++ binary  is dynamically linked to within the binary itself?

Essentially I want to run `ldd` on a binary, without running `ldd`.

The use case is using `dlopen` from `dlfcn.h`. I have a C++ library which is linked to `libpython`, but I don't know if its `libpython3.5m.so`, `libpython3.4m.so`, `libpython2.7.so`, etc...

I want to call

```
void* handle = dlopen( "@PYTHON_LIBRARY@", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL );
```

where `"@PYTHON_LIBRARY@"` resolves to the path to whatever the current libpython the module is currently dynamically linked to.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: can't you try libpython3.5m.so, then libpython3.4m.so, then libpython2.7.so... until it succeeds?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't think it would work like that... you could load an incorrect library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to call `void *handle = dlopen("...", ...)`

Presumably you want to then call `dlsym(handle, "SomePythonSymbol")`.

That is a *pointless* thing to do. Instead of performing dynamic lookup, simply call the `SomePythonSymbol` directly.

To answer your original "what version of libpython am I linked to" question, on a GLIBC-based system you can use [dl_iterate_phdr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html) to enumerate all currently loaded shared libraries.

If you already have a symbol that you know is defined in libpython, [dladdr1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) will make finding the library even easier.

Comment: It turns out to not be pointless when loading pybind11 plugins. If you don't call dlopen, then you can get into issues (e.g. can't find PyFloat_Type) when executing python code that imports modules like ctypes. I don't need to ever call `dlsym`. However, dl_iterate_phdr seems like exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Erotemic Your explanation of what goes wrong makes no sense to me. If you are already linked against `libfoo.so`, then calling `dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY)` is surely a no-op. I'd be curious to see a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve where such `dlopen` makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can read `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/self/map_files`, but this is not portable to other platforms.